# Merge array-of-array with specifics similar values

Tags: php

Imagine that I have this array:

```
$users = [];
$users[0] = [ "Name" => "John Doe", "Age" => 48, 
              "Email" => "john.doe@server-a.com", "Points" => 5 ];
$users[1] = [ "Name" => "John Brother", "Age" => 32, 
              "Email" => "john.brother@server-a.com", "Points" => 8 ];
$users[2] = [ "Name" => "John Doe", "Age" => 48, 
              "Email" => "john.doe@server-b.com", "Points" => 3 ];
$users[3] = [ "Name" => "John Doe", "Age" => 49, 
              "Email" => "john.doe@server-b.com", "Points" => 7 ];
```

In my code, I need merge users when (Same Name + Same Age) or (Same Email), to sum points and return a unique copy of this user, considering the most newer information of this user, if merged.

So, note that:

- `User#0` can merge with `User#2`, because it share (Same Name + Same Age);
- But `User#0` can't merge *directly* with `User#3`, because of they don't have similarity;
- `User#2` can merge with `User#3`, because it share (Same Email);
- So, indirectly, `User#0` **CAN** merge with `User#3` and `User#2`;

The result expected is:

```
$users[] = [ "Name" => "John Brother", "Age" => 32, 
             "Email" => "john.brother@server-a.com", "Points" => 8 ];
$users[] = [ "Name" => "John Doe", "Age" => 49, 
             "Email" => "john.doe@server-b.com", "Points" => 15 ];
```

**Note**: the `User#ID`, after merge, doesn't matter.

Comment: And what have you tried to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a more efficient or elegant approach but you can try something like this:

```
$result = [];
$tmp = [];
array_walk($users, function ($value) use (&$result, &$tmp) {
    $hash = md5($value['Name'].$value['Age']);
    $sum  = $value['Points'];
    $e    = $value['Email'];
    if (array_key_exists($hash, $result)) {
        $sum += $result[$hash]['Points'];
    } elseif (array_key_exists($e, $tmp)) {
        $hash = md5($tmp[$e]['Name'].$tmp[$e]['Age']);
        $sum += $result[$hash]['Points'];
    }
    $result[$hash] = $tmp[$e] = $value;
    $result[$hash]['Points'] = $sum;
});

$users = array_values($result);
var_dump($users);
```

The output is:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Name' => string 'John Doe' (length=8)
      'Age' => int 49
      'Email' => string 'john.doe@server-b.com' (length=21)
      'Points' => int 15
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'Name' => string 'John Brother' (length=12)
      'Age' => int 32
      'Email' => string 'john.brother@server-a.com' (length=25)
      'Points' => int 8
```